# c# wpf mvvm light several views one instance of view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i have two views and one viewModel as dataContext. after starting the app it starts two instances of viewModels. the issue is how to create only one instance. i'm using mvvm light. and sorry for my English :)

Comment: Can you simply make the View Model a singleton?

Comment: what do you mean? i heard about this pattern, but never used them. and don't mind how to implement this on viewModel :)

Comment: i need to share some commands and binding between views

Answer (score 0):

Dont use DataContext use StaticResource instead!

Try this :

For first view

```html
<FirstView.Resources>
  <local:CommonViewModel x:Key="commonVM"/>
</FirstView.Resources>
```

Do the same for your second View. Now when you're binding something, mention the key as a StaticResource like :

```html
<TextBlock Text={Binding someTextProp,Source={StaticResource commonVM}}/>
```

This should work

Comment: Have you implemented *INotifyPropertyChanged* in your ViewModel?

Comment: Do you call RaisePropertyChanged() in the setters of your properties? like :

'public string SelectedName
{
    get { return _selectedName; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedName != value)
        {
            _selectedName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedName");
        }
    }
} '

Comment: yes, sure. im using RaisePropertyChanged(() => ProperyName); in setter. xaml.cs is empty, cause it's following mvvm pattern

Comment: it's only InitializeComponent() there.

Comment: You can use static Properties in the ViewModel. But it is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if I understand what you're saying.
You get two instances of your View-Model, but you actually only want one instance of your View-Model that can be shared between the two Views.

Register your View-Model in the ViewModelLocator Class: 
(It should be created if you made a new MVVM Light project.)

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Model.IDataService, Data>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Model.IDataService, Model.DataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Main property.
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
        "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
        Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
    public MainViewModel Main => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();


    /// <summary>
    /// Cleans up all the resources.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
    }
}
```

Then make sure to get the DataContext for both Views from the name you gave your View-Model in the ViewModelLocator class, in my example it is set as Main. You can do this using the ViewModelLocator as a static resource in your View's XAML code - like this:

```
<Window x:Class="mvvmLight.View.YourView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

It would be nice to see some of your code, that would make it easier to locate the problem.
Paste the DataContext binding of both your Views as well as your View-Model and the ViewModelLocator (if you got one).

Comment: thank you for the reply ! and happy new year :) i'll answer some later